# Unicorn server mongodb and sinatra

Tags: ruby, mongodb, sinatra, unicorn, middleware

So I have been trying to find out more about this.
I am currently building a lightweight API with sinatra + mongodb + unicorn.
Since instance variables inside a middleware app, running on unicorn, only survive per single request, something like this wouldn't work:

```
@connector ||= Mongo::Connector.new 'localhost'
```

That means for each incoming request I create a new Mongo::Connection instance, which after a good few requests, spawns a whole army of mongodb processes on my machine.
I solved the problem by declaring a global variable

```
$connector ||= Mongo::Connector.new 'localhost'
```

But is that the way to go? Is it safe to use this notation?
Please give me your thoughts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you were going to use a global variable then better to use a constant, it has the same scope in practice but signifies that you don't wish it to be reassigned (and you don't).

Better than that though, is a class instance variable. Wide scope, tight control, obvious intent:

```
module AmazingProject
  def self.conn
    @conn ||= Mongo::Connector.new 'localhost'
  end
end

class App < Sinatra::Base
  get "/" do
    AmazingProject.conn.get_all_records # call it from wherever you need it.
  end
end
```

In the context of a Sinatra app, I'd either use that or just put the connection in the `settings` helper.

```
class App < Sinatra::Base

  configure do
    set :conn, { Mongo::Connector.new 'localhost' }
  end

  get "/" do
    settings.conn.do_something_interesting()
  end
end
```

All application instances will have access to `settings.conn`.

Comment: very awesome! I haven't actually tried it yet, but it makes sense, the instance variable will be treated as a constant and will survive for further requests. thanks